# Asp.Net 1 -> Asp.Net 2 upgrade - Machine.Config - unrecognized parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-2.0, upgrade

I am working on upgrading a web app to asp.net 2 from 1.

VS 2008 did its conversion things, and everything is building successfully and has been converted to a web application via the appropriate menu item in VS 2008.

On launching the site using the Asp.net development server I am receiving a configuration error on the appsettings line in the machine config of Unrecognized attribute 'restartOnExternalChanges'.

The app targets asp.net 2 in the projects properties in VS, and the error page indicates similar : Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3053; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3053

The error message seems to indicate I am trying to run this in an asp.net 1 environment, but surely that isnt the case, and if so how do I rectify this.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks,

Comment: What about the application pool?

Comment: Is this relevant when dealing with the WebDev.WebServer?? Doesnt the app pool relate directly to ISS, and would have no effect in this case?

Comment: My bad, I missed the 'using the Asp.net development server' part :P

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your 2.0 framework is ganked. I know you are running in the dev server but do you have an option in IIS for version 2.0?  Re-Run the Microsoft .NET framework V2 installer.

I would just install .NET 3.5SP1  , link is [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=AB99342F-5D1A-413D-8319-81DA479AB0D7&displaylang=en)

Comment: Im trying to re-install but having trouble as this corporate machine is locked down. IIS is set to use v2, and have run aspnet_regiis -i. Will work on trying a re-install, cheers for advice